# Notation of Burnside's group theory book "The theory of finite groups"

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

According to the classification of finite non-abelian groups of order 
$p^4$ in Burnside's book "The theory of finite groups, 1897, pages 87-88" 
one of the types of these groups
is the following family:
$$G(\alpha):=\langle a, b, c
\mid a^{p^2}=b^p=c^p=1, a^b=a^{p+1}, a^c=ab, b^c=a^{\alpha p}b\rangle,$$ 
where $p>3$ and $\alpha=0$, $\alpha=1$ or $\alpha$=any non-residue (mod $p$).

What does "$\alpha$=any non-residue (mod $p$)" mean?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is short for quadratic non-residue  $\mod p$, meaning that $x^2 \equiv \alpha \mod p$ has no solution.